# Git branch is not updated

Tags: git, github

I am working on my app so basically I created several branches:

```
feature/add-contact
feature/edit-contact
feature/show-contact
feature/delete-contact
```

After working on the `edit-contact` and push my files on that branch usually I am getting this on my repository:

[image]

And then after clicking the `compare and pull request` button and then merge it to master, I will checkout to my master branch and will `git pull` to get the latest updates on master branch.

After working on several feature until finally came to `feature/delete-contact` and finish, I decided to go back to `feature/edit-contact` but when I open it, all the codes are not updated even using `git pull`.

I also tried to make changes and try to do some `git push` on the changes I've made on this branch (feature/edit-branch) but I am no longer seeing the `compare and pull request` button that I am seeing above.

1. How do I make sure that each branch that I am passing through get the latest updates on my codes even when I go back to the previous branch I am working with?
2. How do I make sure that I'll get the same pull request again after I push on a previously worked branch?

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

From the question it is not very clear what exactly that you want. I think your question is how to keep your branches updated with the master branch code? If that is the thing that you want to do then you should do

```
git checkout you_branch_name
git pull origin master
```

That will get all the latest changes done on master to your branch.

Answer (score 0):

A git branch is a label pointing at a specific git commit.

If you merge a feature branch into *master*, then the tip of the *master* branch is put ahead to the merge commit with your new feature. When all of your feature branches are merged, *master* contains all of your changes from the various feature branches. Yet your feature branches still point to the commit before their corresponding merge with *master* happened.

[image: Example of a commit graph where two features a and b were merged with master]

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to make sure that each branch that you are working on has the latest updates, you must ensure that any changes you want to be in a branch are 'committed' using the command `git commit -m <your memorable message>`. This will allow you to checkout another branch and make changes. When you eventually come back to the branch you committed your changes to, you should see the code that was previously committed.
2. With regards to `git pull`, in order to guarantee that you get the same pull request again after pushing on a previously worked branch, you must ensure that the pull request doesn't change by ensureing that you don't commit any code to the branch that the pull request depends on. This is because a pull request has a direct one-to-one mapping with a branch.